# 3D hologram without a requirement of screen

Tags: optics, hologram

How can I project a 3D hologram outdoor without a screen?
is it possible to do it?
Basically I just want a hologram of a square shape or a cube in a field at daylight.

Comment: A hologram is not a projection and what you want is utterly impractical to do, even with some "magical technologies", the power requirements for daylight use would be enormous. It's also not clear why it would be necessary. One can achieve exactly the same thing (and probably much better) with VR glasses (well, as of today VR deep sea diving "goggles").

Comment: Imagine a person looking at the hologram.  The light that _apparently_ comes from any point on the holographic object has to _actually_ come from something that lies on the straight line from the viewer's eye through the point.  The "something" can be between the eye and the apparent point, or it can be beyond the apparent point, but what really matters is, it has to be true for _every_ point in the holographic image.  There has to be a 2D "window" that the viewer looks through, or a 2D surface that the viewer looks at.